# Authenticating a user with twitter inside chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, twitter

I am building a chrome extension that requires users to sign in with their Twitter account.

I am querying my remote server to fetch the twitter sign in link. But I am not sure how I should proceed thereafter.

I tried using `chrome.browserAction.setPopup` by creating an HTML page with `<iframe>` tag. But twitter doesn't allow that. I even tried setting `window.location` but that isn't allowed in chrome either (for obvious security reasons).

Can this be achieved? If no, what other authentication techniques (except the username:password combination method) are generally used for browser extension?